# Catching karate api test failure in jenkins pipeline

Tags: api, rest, karate

Hello all can anyone show a snippet for catching karate api test failure in a jenkins pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Karate exports the JUnit XML format which is understood by all CI tools, including Jenkins. You can search for more details in the Karate documentation.

So all you need to do is tell Jenkins where to find it.

In other words the answer to your question is the same as how you get a JUnit test failure in a Jenkins pipeline.